# web page running on single instance?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, multi-user

I'm writing a webpage should be used by multi user at the same time. 
The page contains some filters ,so each user should get results as they filtered.

The problem is , once user A change a filter on his own page,  user B's filter is changed to user A's choice.

The way it updates filters is once a filter control is set, do Response.Redirect("search.aspx?filter_a=12&filter_b=1&....."),  then read query string to set filters search results.

symptom 1:

```
time 0: user A load page as first , all filter off.

time 0:  user B load page as first , all filter off.

time 1 : User A set filter  a b c On, submit

time 2 : User B set filter  x on, then page submit  

time 3:  After User B's page gets refreshed, User B see   filter a b c and x On.
```

symptom 2:

```
time 0: user A load page as first , all filter off.

time 0:  user B load page as first , all filter off.

time 1: user A set  filter  a on, submit. then user A's page filter a is on.

time 2: user B do nothing just refresh page,  will see filter a is on.
```

the result sould be:

```
on A's page only filter a b c  are On

on B's page only filter x is on.
```

It makes me feel that, the webpage is only running on a same instance, that everybody shares it's controls.

How can i set it to multi instances to support different user?

Run on same machine with different bowers,different machines,different machines on different public IPs, all get the problem.

Comment: Could you please share the code behind file,to understand what actually you are doing in c# code?

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess since there is no source code provided.
My guess is that you have static objects in your Application memory that are shared between the different users for different requests.
Try using instances that are tied to individual requests and not to application.